# JavaScript not working for elements routed with ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the code below, the the `#test` button works, but the `#calendarButton` does not. There must be some reason that my `header.html` cannot access my Javascript.

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Lifting Analytics </title>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class"container" ng-app="app">
        <header ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></header> 
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <button id="test">test</button> // This button works

  </body>
</html>
```

header.html (This button doesn't work)

```
...
<button id="calendarButton" class="btn btn-default">Calendar</button> 
...
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function(){
    console.log("in");
    alert("in");
  });
  $('#calendarButton').click(function(){
    console.log("in");
    alert("in");
  });
});
```

app.js (not sure if this is necessary)

Also, how do I refer to this file? the router? Sorry it's my first day with angular.

```
angular
.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .state('record', {
            url: '/record',
            templateUrl: 'templates/record.html'
        })
        .state('calendar', {
            url: '/calendar',
            templateUrl: 'templates/calendar.html',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
            }
        })
        .state('graph', {
            url: '/graph',
            templateUrl: 'templates/graph.html'
        })
}])
```

Comment: `document.ready` is useless in angular, use angular event handlers

Answer (score 1):

If you're routing using ng-include or ng-route, the elements within those routes don't render until the applicable route is invoked.  That's why the calendar button click event isn't being captured - it doesn't exist at the time you're binding..

To get it to work, you could try this..

```
$('body').on('click', '#calendarButton', function() {...}); //a delegate
```

Though, I would not recommend doing this, as it is not the "angular" way.  What would be better is something like the following..

Within your view..

```
<button id="calendarButton" ng-click="clickFn()"/>
```

Within your controller...

```
$scope.clickFn = function() { ... }
```